# Saving Checkbox states

Tags: android, checkbox

I am very new and would appreciate if someone could demonstrate the code required to save a number of checkbox states in java inside of an android application.

Say i have a list of tools (Ten or more) a user needs to complete a task and would like them to be able to check off each one and have that data saved (within the app, not sQlite) so that it is recorded when they return to the application.

I have some idea of how this is done but really feel like i need to see the code to understand correctly.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.CheckBox;

public class CheckBoxTest extends Activity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.checkboxtest);
    CheckBox cb1,cb2,cb3,cb4;

    cb1 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
    cb2 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
    cb3 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox3);
    cb4 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox4);   
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the below code to store and retrive the data in SharedPreference. Your save each check box state in SharedPreference

//To get value from SharedPreference

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("PROJECT_NAME", android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
boolean value = preferences.getBoolean("KEY", false);
String value = preferences.getString("KEY");
```

//To Save value in SharedPreference

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("PROJECT_NAME", android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
editor.putString("KEY", value);
editor.putBoolean("KEY", value);
editor.commit();
```

look into it few minor changes::::

```
public class CheckBoxTest extends Activity implements OnCheckedChangeListener {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.favorites_add_button);
            CheckBox cb1,cb2,cb3,cb4;

            cb1 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
            cb1.setChecked(getFromSP("cb1"));
            cb1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
            cb2 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
            cb2.setChecked(getFromSP("cb2"));
            cb2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
            cb3 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox3);
            cb3.setChecked(getFromSP("cb3"));
            cb3.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
            cb4 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox4);
            cb4.setChecked(getFromSP("cb4"));
            cb4.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

        }
        private boolean getFromSP(String key){
        SharedPreferences preferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("PROJECT_NAME", android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return preferences.getBoolean(key, false);
        }
        private void saveInSp(String key,boolean value){
        SharedPreferences preferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("PROJECT_NAME", android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean(key, value);
        editor.commit();
        }
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                boolean isChecked) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            switch(buttonView.getId()){
            case R.id.checkBox1:
            saveInSp("cb1",isChecked);
            break;
            case R.id.checkBox2:
            saveInSp("cb2",isChecked);
            break;

            case R.id.checkBox3:
            saveInSp("cb3",isChecked);
            break;

            case R.id.checkBox4:
            saveInSp("cb4",isChecked);
            break;
            }

        }
        }
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks do much for your help and patience. Lots of learning left to do but this was a huge help for me now i can see what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I tried the above but after rebooting or restarting my android device, I would lose the checked state of the options menu. I'd say, to solve the problem:

You have 2 options:

1. Get shared preference value during the life-cycle of the activity.
2. Call `.clear` before `.commit`

See my answer:

[Android Persistent Checkable Menu in Custom Widget After Reboot Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36939380/android-persistent-checkable-menu-in-custom-widget-after-reboot-android)